# Visual Studio Extension that alters the build process

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, vspackage

After reading documentation I have concluded that developing an own "VSPackage" is the most powerful way of extending Visual Studio's behaviour.

Now I want to build an extension which modifies the build (compilation) behaviour of VS for C/C++ applications.
Is there any getting-started guide or documentation on this?

Most available tutorials seem to focus on GUI aspects.

Comment: You need to extend mśbuild, some nuget packages do that, not a visx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to modify the .vcxproj-file, it controls the build process for c++ in Visual Studio 2015.

You can read more about the build process for c++ in VS2015 here:
[Building C++ Projects in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7s88b19e.aspx)

If you're going to have several project that are going to use the same build process you should look into creating a project template instead of an extension. Take a look here to get started https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx

Good luck!